# Eloquent Query: Get relationship property with certain columns only

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a Many-To-Many relationship between two models: Story and Tag. There is a part of my app where I need to return only two columns from the Tag model for a given Story. I want to accomplish something like this:

```
Route::get('taglist/{id}', function($id) {
    $tags = Story::find($id)->tags->select('name', 'id as value')->get();

    return $tags;
});
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but I need to have it where I am returning a collection of Tag(s) with only those two fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the method `->tags()` in order to access the relationship builder to do your queries, so this one should work:

```
Route::get('taglist/{id}', function($id) {
    $tags = Story::find($id)->tags()->select('name', 'id as value')->get();

    return $tags;
});
```